# I need an algorithm that will return a point into a list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, point

I am using Zelle's Python graphics library and I need a little help creating an algorithm to return a number in a list.

Basically I have 5x7 board separated into a 100x100 pixel grid. That corresponds with a list such as this.

```
| 0| 1| 2| 3| 4|  
| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|  
|10|11|12|13|14|  
|15|16|17|18|19|  
|20|21|22|23|24|  
|25|26|27|28|29|  
|30|31|32|33|34|
```

I need an algorithm that would take the center point of a grid from a mouse click and turn it into the number corresponding with the list. For example the point (50,50) would return 0, and the point (150,150) would return 6, and etc.

Thank you very much for taking the time to help figure out this algorithm!

Answer (score 5):

```py
In [1]: def f(x, y):
   ...:     return y // 100 * 5 + x // 100
   ...: 

In [2]: f(50, 50)
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: f(150, 150)
Out[3]: 6
```

Comment: @Trevor: You might want to use variable to hold all those magic numbers in your program in case you ever need or want to change them. It'll make it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
def point_to_xy(x_mouse,y_mouse):
    x_pos = math.floor(x_mouse/100) #or x_mouse // 100
    y_pos = math.floor(y_mouse/100) #or y_mouse // 100
    return x_pos,y_pos

def xy_to_index(x_pos,y_pos):
    array_0_width = 5 #the width of the 2d array
    #position is y*width + x_offset
    return y_pos*array_0_width+x_pos

x,y = point_to_xy(mouse.x,mouse.y)
print xy_to_index(x,y)
```

I think that would work

```
>>> x,y = point_to_xy(150,150) #x,y=1,1
>>> print xy_to_index(x,y)
6.0
>>> x,y = point_to_xy(50,50) # x,y=0,0
>>> print xy_to_index(x,y)
0.0
```